# Why at the moment of sorting the object vector the counter of created objects of the class is increased by an additional 2?

Tags: c++

There is a `HasPtr` class:

```
class HasPtr
{
    friend void swap(HasPtr&, HasPtr&);
public:
    HasPtr(const std::string& s = std::string()) 
       : ps(new std::string(s)), i(0), use(new std::size_t(1)) {}
    HasPtr(const HasPtr& hp) : ps(hp.ps), i(hp.i), use(hp.use) { ++*use; }
    HasPtr& operator=(HasPtr hp)
    {
        swap(*this, hp);
        return *this;
    }
    ~HasPtr()
    {
        if (--*use == 0)
        {
            delete ps;
            delete use;
        }
    }
    bool operator<(const HasPtr& rhs)
    {
        return *ps < *rhs.ps;
    }
private:
    unsigned i;
    std::size_t* use; // counter
    std::string* ps;
};

inline void swap(HasPtr& lhs, HasPtr& rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.ps, rhs.ps);
    swap(lhs.i, rhs.i);
}
```

The main function also initializes the vector and then sorts and displays the result:

```
int main()
{
    HasPtr a("A"), b("B"), c("C"), d("D"), e("E");
    std::vector<HasPtr> vec{d, a, c, e, b};
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for (auto letter : vec)
    {
        std::cout << *letter.ps << " " << letter.get_use() << " " << std::endl;;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Question:** Why does it turn out that every object in the vector has a counter of 3 and how can this be fixed?

Comment: My initial question to you is: why is it important to keep track of the usage?  Are you developing a smart pointer class?

Comment: `HasPtr a("A"); std::vector<HasPtr> vec{a};` will give you a count of two, since you then have two copies: One being the object `a` and one being `vec[0]`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, this is a training class implemented as a pointer

Comment: Your `swap` doesn't swap `use` pointer, I guess that might be the source of 3rd object?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
Thanks, I hadn't noticed that. Where does the 3rd one come from? And how can I fix the code so that the counter counts the objects correctly?

Comment: @iamnotevg -- But regardless of the use_count, it could be 100, does it reflect the number of objects currently in use?  If so, then there is no bug and your code is working as you designed it.  Thus there isn't anything to "fix".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting into a vector will create a second copy, increasing the use-count to `2`.

Then you have the loop `for (auto letter : vec)` which iterates using *values*. I.e. it creates copies of the object inside the vector, increasing the count to `3` while inside the loop.

If you iterate using references instead, as in `for (auto const& letter : vec)`, then the use-count should be left at `2`.